# putting a string into *this inside the constructor in C++

Tags: c++, string, this

In the class constructor I'm creating a string and want to store it into `*this`.
This code inside the constructor doesn't work:

```
// Inside the class constructor
string str1 = "hello";
*this = str1;
```

Should I use some other datatype instead of `string str1`? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you overload `operator=(std::string const&)`?

Comment: What is the type of `*this`?

Comment: WHat are you trying to achieve - how is this constructor called and what type is it

Comment: The code provided makes no sense out of context.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see your class defintion, but given it is not present let me do a long shot and try to guess what's the problem.

When you declare a class, it is initially empty. You cannot store anything in a constructor.

```
class Empty {
   Empty() { /* can't do much here */ }
}
```

Classes consists of member fields, and those can store data for you. What you might want to do is something like this:

```
class String {
    std::string member;
    String() {
        std::string str1 = "hello";
        member = str1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`*this` it is instance of your class object.

you couldn't do `*this= str1;` until your class isn't `std::string`

Comment: Or, it could provide a conversion assignment operator `operator=(std::string const&)`